# Smaller code-128 barcodes generation in Java

Tags: java, size, barcode

I am new to Barcode generation. I am generating code-128 barcodes with Java libraries like barbecue.jar and barcode.jar. By using those libraries, for the value 123456-AB, the minimum barcode size (width) is 1.5 inch. For the same code, by using Zebra Designer Pro 2 tool, the barcode minimum size is 1.4 cm. I need to generate small barcodes in my application. Here my doubts are

1. Is there any difference to generate barcodes in Zebra Designer Pro 2 tool and with Java library?
2. Is there any relationship between fonts and size of barcode?
   Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the code from [the barcode example](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-components/java/user-manual.html) you can define any size you need. By changing the bc size and scale factor.

```
BarCode bc = new BarCode();
bc.setSize(400, 200);
// create image
java.awt.image.BufferedImage
image = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(
    bc.getSize().width, bc.getSize()
    .height, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED
);
// get graphic context of image
java.awt.Graphics imgGraphics = image.createGraphics();

((Graphics2D)imgGraphics).scale(0.5, 0.5); //adding scaling of the image

// paint barcode in graphics context of image
bc.paint(imgGraphics);
```